# How to keep the search engines away from some pages on my domain

Tags: html, meta

I've build a admin control panel for my website. I don't want the control panel app to end up in a search engine, since there's really no need for it. I did some research and i've found that by using the following tag, i can probably achieve my goal

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

Is this true? Is there other methods more reliable? I'm asking because i'm scare i could mess things up if i'm using the wrong method, and i do want search engines to search my site, just not the control panel...
Thanks

Comment: That should be enough. Don't worry too much, hardly anyone would find on Google pages that have no relevant keywords or content on them.

Comment: Nothing forces web crawlers to adhere to instructions in robots.txt, but Googlebot claims to play fair :) https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en

Comment: In addition to blocking robots, you can assist them with a 'sitemap.xml' file that describes the routes you do want indexed. [Google: About Sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true, but on top of doing that, for even more security, in your `.htaccess` file, you should set this:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

And in you should create a new file in the root of your domain, named `robots.txt` with this content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

And you can be sure that they won't index your content ;)

Comment: Indeed, but what the op seeks is a way to stop them, and what I offered is the most workable solution to prevent them doing that I think.

Answer (score 1):

Google will honor the meta tag by completely dropping the page from their index ([source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93708?hl=en)) however other crawlers might just simply decide to ignore it.

In that particular sense meta tags are more reliable with Google because by simply using `robots.txt` any other external source that is explicitly linking to your admin page (for whatever reason) will make your page appear in Google index (though without any content which will probably result in some SERP leeching).